# Xamarin, размеры элементов

Tags: c#, xamarin

Допустим:

```
<StackLayout Padding = "0, 10, 0, 10">
```

Цифры этих отступов - это пиксели? Или dpi? Никак найти не могу.

Comment: Не знаю как в Xamarin, но в UWP это *эффективные пиксели*

Comment: @АндрейNOP, было бы замечательно конечно, но информация не точна, подожду еще. Однако спасибо за это определение, я слышал, что с приходом WPF была решена проблема разрешений, теперь понял как :)

Comment: Странно, тоже не нахожу в документации. А в xamarin работает такое: `Padding="1in"`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP увы, нет, не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не пиксели, это некоторые единицы, которые определяются для каждой платформы отдельно.

Вот что думает Microsoft на эту тему, перевод корявый, но в целом понятно:

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05